# MongoDB.Driver expression not supported

Tags: asp.net, .net, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a Model in .NET core. In my model i have multiple list objects. Each list object have list object to. Now,When I try to query data using projection, I am getting,Mongodb.driver linq expression not supported,the problem doesn't arise when i access an entity from list,But when i need to access data where i need to query through multiple list,i get that `Expression not supported` exception.

I tried

```
var projection = Builders<T>.Projection
                .Include(x => x.jobInformations.Select(y => y.CommentsData.Select(y => y.cmtId)))


            return _collection.Find(filter).Project<T>(projection).ToList();
```

Here jobInformations is a list and CommentsData also a list,cmtId is an entity of commentdata,i need to get that using .Include projection. How can i achieve that goal?

Comment: see `Unsupported LINQ ..` paragraph here https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.18/frequently_encountered_issues/